Why the dual group of a locally compact group is a set?
If $G$
is a locally compact group, the definition of the dual group of $G$
is the set of all equivalence classes of irreducible unitary representations of $G$
, denoted by $\widehat{G}$
. But why this is well-defined? If for every Hilbert space $H$
, we have a irreducible unitary representations of $G$
on $H$
, and they are not unitary equivalence, then the number of the element of $\widehat{G}$
are too many to be a set. So how can we prove $\widehat{G}$
is a set? Use Schur's Lemma?

This question has been asked-and-answered on MathOverflow.  Generally speaking, cross-posting of identical questions is discouraged.
